Is it safe to use the dnd 3.5 skill system in pathfinder 1e?
I really like the DND 3.5 skill point system, I think it opens up more doors to make different choices, but I like the Pathfinder system much better for many other things like classes (I intend to keep the combat maneuvers from Pathfinder 1e, which are easier, and also leave perception as a skill).
Would it be safe to adapt the system, leaving the same number of skills and ranks gained per level?
Another part was about whether it would be worth using the Pathfinder 1e concentration system (it seems to be much more difficult since the DC is 10 + damage + spell level and DND is only 10 + damage)?

The reverse may also be of interest here.

Yes, though I recommend against it.
Both D&D 3.5e and Pathfinder 1e produce skills that—when they are a class skill and you invest in them—you get a “base” bonus of (your level) + (one ability modifier) + 3. (You can add items, feats, spells, etc. on top of this base level, of course, in both systems.)
(You do say “leaving the same number of skills and ranks gained per level,” which is yeah, fine—so long as you include the ×4 multiplier at 1st level. That’s crucial to the D&D 3.5e system, that’s where the +3 comes from. You need that bit. I think this is what you meant, but just in case.)
Since the numbers are the same, they’re pretty much interchangeable. The only number that substantially changes is the number of ranks you have in a given skill: D&D 3.5e, effectively, includes the +3 as ranks, while Pathfinder 1e just gives you a +3 bonus that is not part of your ranks. Skill rank requirements are therefore usually—when it’s intended for characters who have the skill as a class skill and are invested in it—3 ranks higher in D&D 3.5e than they are in Pathfinder 1e. So you should increase any skill rank requirements for Pathfinder 1e feats and prestige classes by +3 when using the D&D 3.5e skill system.
So it’s no problem to use the D&D 3.5e system in Pathfinder. That said—as someone who generally much prefers D&D 3.5e over Pathfinder 1e—I don’t recommend it.
But first, you did have a secondary question:
Concentration: either way
Pathfinder made concentration no longer a skill, but instead just a spellcaster mechanic. This has advantages (spellcasters are no longer required to spend skill points on a skill they cannot live without) and disadvantages (it’s harder to buff), and the end result is that concentration is a little harder in Pathfinder than it was in D&D 3.5e, which was done on purpose to slightly nerf spellcasters (who are hugely overpowered in both systems). You’re welcome to use whichever version you like; it doesn’t really matter that much.
The only concern would be if you wish to port the 3.5e Tome of Battle supplement to Pathfinder. That book uses the Concentration skill for non-spellcaster things (primarily via the Diamond Mind discipline), and it’s a little unclear what the best approach to handling that is in an environment that has Pathfinder-style concentration. Personally, since I primarily tend to think in terms of 3.5e and port things I like from Pathfinder into 3.5e, rather than the other way around, I usually prefer to keep Concentration as a skill for the sake of this book—it’s easily the best book written for either system, so its needs for Concentration trumps any advantage I see in Pathfinder’s version. But even if you did want to use Tome of Battle, there are plenty of ways of handling it with Pathfinder-style concentration if that was your preference.
Consideration: cross-class skills
One of the perennial complaints about D&D 3.5e skills—and the primary motivation, so far as I can tell, for the Pathfinder changes—is the complexity and painfulness of cross-class skills. Doubling the skill point cost of ranks in cross-class skills is immensely punitive—to the point that it’s basically impossible to seriously consider bothering with them unless absolutely forced to do so for a prerequisite (and even then, it’s a very good reason to reconsider whether you need the thing that requires it). And simply put, skills aren’t good enough to be worth that effort.
But really, that is the more important thing: skills aren’t that significant. And the D&D 3.5e system is vastly more complex, at least once you start multiclassing. Your skill rank maximum cares only that a skill was a class skill for any class, but the skill point cost depends on whether the skill is a class skill for this class, that you’re leveling up in. That means there is no way to do skills for a higher-level multiclassed character “all at once”—you must go through and figure out which skill ranks were earned at which levels. It’s tedious and error-prone, and again, skills just aren’t worth the work. It’s also confusing for a lot of new players, the whole “one thing cares about any class, the other thing cares about this class,” thing. Keeping track of that is something a lot of new players in D&D 3.5e struggle with.
Consideration: Intelligence bonuses
In D&D 3.5e, gaining Intelligence increases the number of skill points you gain going forward, but does not increase the number of skill points from levels you already have. In Pathfinder 1e, gaining Intelligence retroactively increases skill points for previous levels. For example, consider a 1st-level wizard with 16 Intelligence (20 or 5 skill points, depending on whether the 3.5e 4× multiplier is in use), and a 1st-level sorcerer with 10 Intelligence (8/2 skill points). Now imagine that the latter picks up a headband of intellect +6 (an unreasonable item for a 1st-level character but for the sake of example), so that both characters now have one level in a 2+Int class and Int 16:

No retroactive skill points, à la D&D 3.5e: the sorcerer still has just 8/2 skill points.
Retroactive skill points, à la Pathfinder 1e: the sorcerer has the same 20/5 skill points as the wizard.

This is important because it means that, in Pathfinder, you only need to know someone’s levels and final Intelligence value to figure out their skill points. If they’re single-classed (or have levels in classes all with the same base skill points), it’s just a single simple multiplication. In D&D 3.5e, you need to know exactly when each point of Intelligence was gained. This is very similar to the problem with skills that are cross-class for some but not all class levels, and makes creating higher-level characters immensely painful.
Consideration: skill list
The D&D 3.5e skill list is, quite simply, much too large. Consider: a typical party has

a cleric or druid (4+Int skills; no need for Int)
a barbarian or fighter or paladin (2+Int skills; little-to-no need for Int)
a rogue (8+Int skills; little-to-no need for Int)
a wizard or sorcerer (2+Int skills; lot of Int for the wizard but no need for the sorcerer)

All told, you’re looking at 16-22 skill points per level, depending on whether you have a wizard and how high they’ve gotten their Int (at higher levels, you might have a bit more). Because your skill rank maximum (for class skills) increases 1/level, how many skill points you get each level dictates how many skills you can keep maximized. The D&D 3.5e skill list has over 50 skills on it (counting all the Knowledge skills separately and a few non-core skills). That means more than half the skills in the game are going to be completely ignored by the entire party. They’ll have to, they won’t have enough skill points to do otherwise. Moreover, plenty of skills will be taken by multiple people: both spellcasters are definitely taking Concentration, and almost-certainly taking Spellcraft. Listen and Spot are pretty key for everyone. Balance is also weirdly important to get to 5 ranks (in order to avoid being flat-footed by anything that forces you to balance)—that one you might even do cross-class, though 7th level is pretty late to finally get it. The cleric will definitely want Knowledge (religion), or the druid Knowledge (nature), but that doesn’t mean the wizard won’t get those skills: their class skill list doesn’t really offer them a lot of other options. So really, you’re probably looking at the party—all together—only bothering with about a third of the game’s skills.
It’s convenient, then, that a ton of skills are worthless.
Even before Pathfinder was a thing, D&D 3.5e games would routinely consolidate skills to reduce this mismatch between skills available and skill points available. Stuff like Pathfinder’s Acrobatics combining 3.5e’s Balance, Jump, and Tumble was found in most games out there. Actually, most games went farther than Pathfinder in this respect—Pathfinder has fewer skills, but it’s still 35—still more than any party is likely to be able to cover.
Conclusion
Yes, you can certainly do this; it won’t cause any substantial problems beyond the problems inherent in the 3.5e skill system. But I would encourage you to consider those problems carefully, because they are very real. Pathfinder does better (though there is, frankly, still room for improvement).

An important note, which I never see mentioned: Pathfinder's skill points are retroactive. This, along with certain other traits makes class order not matter. a->b = b->a. This effectively grants the entire PF skill system the mathematical property of being commutative. (To me, that is a highly desirable trait when building characters.)

@martixy Yeah, that’s another one that I often saw in 3.5e before Pathfinder came along. Ultimately only really tends to matter for wizards or similar, but yeah, it really matters for wizards or similar.

Do you keep a list of your house rules anywhere? They would make for excellent reading.

@J.Mini I don’t; I have gamed pretty much exclusively with the same group for years, so we’re all pretty well on the same page and can amicably handle anything else on an ad hoc basis. I used to have a list written up, but that forum no longer exists, and anyway I suspect I’d disagree with large chunks of it at this point.

This is nitpicky towards the point you're making with your example, but I thought that Intelligence changes from magical items didn't increase skill points in PF1e because they weren't technically permanent increases? And that's why the headbands of intellect and other intelligence-increasing items instead have hardcoded skills baked into them that you get alongside the ability increase, with skill rank = character level.

@Idran Any bonus to an ability score that lasts more than 24 hours counts as permanent once it’s gone on for 24 hours. That includes headband of intellect. The FAQ states that the skills baked into the items themselves is the same bonus and not an additional one. But yeah, the wording is... basically not that, and this is really just yet another case of stealth errata in the FAQ.
